# How to generate swagger ui and then swagger.json file for different environment like Dev,Qa and prod with express-swagger-generator

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

How to generate swagger ui and then swagger.json file for different enviroment like Dev,Qa and prod
with express-swagger-generator

i'm trying http://localhost:3000/v1 for swagger UI view but it gives error as Cannot GET /v1.
is i am using right link to check swagger UI ? or not.
also how to retrieve swagger.json for different environment

```
 // my app.js file is
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    const expressSwagger = require('express-swagger-generator')(app);
    
    let options = {
        swaggerDefinition : {
            info                : {
                description : 'This is a sample server',
                title       : 'Swagger',
                version     : '1.0.0'
            },
            host                : 'localhost:3000',
            basePath            : '/v1',
            produces            : [ 'application/json', 'application/xml' ],
            schemes             : [ 'http', 'https' ],
            securityDefinitions : {
                JWT : {
                    type        : 'apiKey',
                    in          : 'header',
                    name        : 'Authorization',
                    description : ''
                }
            }
        },
        basedir           : __dirname, //app absolute path
        files             : [ './swagger/swagger.js' ] //Path to the API handle folder
    };
    expressSwagger(options);
    
    app.use(require('./routes/routes'));
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('running on', 3000);
    });
    
    // ./routes/routes file 
    
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.post('/swag', (req, res) => {
        let email = req.body.email;
        console.log(email);
        res.json(email);
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
    
    // ./swagger/swagger.js file
    /**
     * This function comment is parsed by doctrine
     * @route POST /swag
     * @group foo - Operations about user
     * @param {string} email.body.required - username or email - eg: user@domain
     * @returns {object} 200 - An array of user info
     * @returns {Error}  default - Unexpected error
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using wrong link for swagger ui view correct link is http://localhost:3000/api-docs
for swagger.json link is http://localhost:3000/api-docs.json